# how to count chars in substrings?

Tags: count, char

I have the next input:

RRS, RSS, SSD,  SDD and a value for each string like, 1, 2, 1 and 1.

I would like to know how to get them organized like this:

R R S S D D

1 3 4 4 2 1

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's like Domino isn't it?

1. Find the word that starts with two letters that no other word ends with. Start with this to build the result string.
2. Find the word that starts with the last two characters the so far built result string ends with. Add its last character.
3. Continue with 2 until no word remains.

With every word you must also add its points to the letter positions. So for word n add its value to position n, n+1 and n+2.

```
111
 222
  111
   111
======
134421
```

Comment: yes, this helps, I needed to add it's value to position but I still have trouble to transform it to code... I've in the file columns and in one column are the letters and in the other I have the values. So should I use a hash with position as key?